# Creating a temporary User in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need :project_owners to invite new :project_participants to a project.

Much like in Basecamp, the :project_owner needs to be able to assign the new :project_participant to projects prior to them completing their full profile (their profile will show "invited" status until they complete their profile).

Once the :project_participant has created a profile their project/index should automatically include any projects they were assigned to prior to finalising their profile.

Comment: Which gem are you using for authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authlogic is used for authentication. You should use 'declarative_authorization' or 'CanCan' for authorization.

Authentication gems are used to check whether a user's record exist in database or not and authorization gems are used to check their privileges. You should check out railscasts for more information.

[This](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=declarative%20authorization%20railscasts&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization&ei=PyoRT-r-AsH4rQeF7aTpAQ&usg=AFQjCNGxBD9xOg2NSPV3lcGHGtVOmVUUdw&sig2=J1xF03Logp8nIw1xKweC6w) on is for declarative_authorization and this one is for [CanCan](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cancan%20railscasts&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan&ei=TyoRT6jDKJHIrQeM65nuAQ&usg=AFQjCNGj6KrtvIMLpTxtLyMmDglB7Wu1nQ&sig2=-OoN0XoVgc6MIpXhsV0xEA).

Once you set privilages you can create method to let you project_owner invite other users and you can assign them temporary status in your database. I this CanCan is best suitable for your needs.